# C# Как создать бота на свой аккаунт

Tags: telegram-bot

Например есть личный телеграмм аккаунт, я хочу что бы я автоматически репостил новые сообщения из всех групп в которые я вступил другому человеку или в свою группу.

Дайте пожалуйста основу кода хотя бы, или же гайд как делать, если в этом языке такое не возможно скажите пожалуйста на каком можно?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью BotFather создаешь бота. https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots#botfather.

Пример для с#.
https://m.habr.com/ru/post/277079/

Не забудь в nuget добавить библиотеку для работы с telegram api. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Api/

Comment: Здраствуйте, а есть какой-то уже пример готовых, и ещё как "Не забудь в nuget добавить библиотеку для работы с telegram api. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Api/" как это сделать?

Comment: Конечно. Ботов сейчас полно и на любом языке, так как с api удобно работать. Пример https://github.com/extremecodetv/Telegram-Bot-Tutorial и туториал https://youtu.be/iOFQ8CyF6wk

Comment: а есть пример бота на мой личный аккаунт, не то что бы пример а хоты бы заготовку.